# pandas get all the consecutive rows until the column value changes

Tags: pandas

Lets say I have a dataframe like below:

```
   pid    name
0  5         A
1  5         X
2  5         C
3  5         Q
4  3         H
5  3         E
6  4         U
7  5         J
```

I don't know what is the value of `pid` in the first row in advance, but I would like to get all the rows from the beginning until the value of `pid` changes. So in this case, all the consecutive rows with pid = 5 should be printed. Note that the last row that has pid=5 should not be in the results.

So the result will be:

```
   pid    name
0  5         A
1  5         X
2  5         C
3  5         Q
```

`Name` is just a column without any specific considerations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
df_final =  df[df.pid.diff().ne(0).cumsum().eq(1)]

Out[909]:
   pid name
0    5    A
1    5    X
2    5    C
3    5    Q
```